# Subtract value of two columns (From & To) and put the result to a different column (Total) in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've a Kendo grid. I want to subtract value of two columns (From & To) and put the result to Total on the fly. So if I change any value in "To"/"From" column I want to see reflection on Total column. e.g. From = 2, To = 4 then Total is 2 as soon as it gets changed in To/From. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

```
$("#HoleGrid").kendoGrid({

    dataSource: {

        transport: {

            read: {
                url: "GetHoleData",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
            },
            update: {
                url: "UpdateHoleData",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
            },
            create: {
                url: "CreateHoleData",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
            },
            parameterMap: function (HoleData, operation) {
                if (operation != "read") {                   
                    return kendo.stringify(HoleData.models);                    
                }
            }
        },

        serverPaging: false,
        pageSize: 10,
        batch: true,

        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false },
                    Hole: { editable: true, nullable: false },
                    From: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },
                    To: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },
                    Total: { editable: true }                   
                }
            }            
        }
    },

    editable: {
        mode: "inline",
        createAt: "bottom"
    },

    toolbar: ["create"],
    sortable: true,
    autoBind: false,

    columns:
        [
            { field: "Hole", width: 90, title: "Hole" },
            { field: "From", width: 90, title: "From" },
            { field: "To", width: 90 },
            { field: "Total", width: 70, title: "Total"},
            { command: ["edit"], title: "Action", width: "175px" }
        ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an observable kind a thing in kendo. But I didn't see any kind of reference so far. I made a work around for you. But until you get a proper solution try this if you want.

```
{
                field: "From", width: 90, title: "From", editor: function (container, options) {
                    var input = $("<input name='" + options.field + "'/>");
                    input.appendTo(container);

                    input.kendoNumericTextBox({
                        min: 0,
                        change: function (e) {
                            $("#HoleGrid .k-grid-edit-row").children().first().next().next().next().text(options.model.To - options.model.From);
                        },
                        spin: function (e) {
                            $("#HoleGrid .k-grid-edit-row").children().first().next().next().next().text(options.model.To - options.model.From);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            {
                field: "To", width: 90, editor: function (container, options) {
                    var input = $("<input name='" + options.field + "'/>");
                    input.appendTo(container);

                    input.kendoNumericTextBox({
                        min: 0,
                        change: function (e) {                            
                            $("#HoleGrid .k-grid-edit-row").children().first().next().next().next().text(options.model.To - options.model.From);
                        },
                        spin: function (e) {
                            $("#HoleGrid .k-grid-edit-row").children().first().next().next().next().text(options.model.To - options.model.From);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            { field: "Total", width: 70, title: "Total" },
```

And on the code behind update Total with To - From and save it in DB. So user refresh the grid they wouldn't see any discrepancies. Hope this may help for now.

Answer (score 3):

Add this event function to  your grid code:

> ```
> save: function (e) {
>     var grid = $('#HoleGrid').data('kendoGrid');
>     for (var field in e.values);
>     if (field === 'To' || field === 'From') {
>         e.model.set('Total', e.model.To - e.model.From);
>     }
>     grid.refresh();
> }
> ```

Comment: I actually need something where I change value on To or From then straight away I need to see changes on Total. Actually before save or anything. Just straight forward calculation.

Comment: @user3157277 To only display total value without refreshing grid you can change this function like that:     `var grid = $('#HoleGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    for (var field in e.values);
    if (field === 'To' || field === 'From') { 
        var uid = e.model.uid;
        var value = e.model.To - e.model.From;
        $('#HoleGrid').find('tr[uid="'+uid +'"] td[dataname="'+field+'"]').text(kendo.toString(value));`

Comment: @j4ro Please add your new solution with "Add Another Answer" so everyone can get benefited. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahib Solution added.

Answer (score 0):

To only display total value without refreshing grid you can change this function like that:

```
save: function (e) {
    var grid = $('#HoleGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    for (var field in e.values);
    if (field === 'To' || field === 'From') {
        var uid = e.model.uid;
        var value = e.model.To - e.model.From;
        $('#HoleGrid').find('tr[uid="'+uid+'"].find('td[dataname="'+field+'"]').text(kendo.toString(value));
    }
}
```